# RxJs: Paginate through API recursively and find value from list

Tags: javascript, rxjs, operators, expand, pagination

I am using rxjs v6.4.0. I am trying to paginate through an API searching for a very specific channel where name equals "development". I am using `expand` to recursively call the API and get new pages. The end result gives me a concatenated list of channels. Then I filter out all channels where name not equal to "development". However I am getting an error: `TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

```
const Rx = require('rxjs')
const Rx2 = require('rxjs/operators')

const getChannel = (cursor) => {
  return this.service.getData(`${url}?cursor=${cursor || ''}`)
      .pipe(Rx2.map(resp => JSON.parse(resp.body)))
      .pipe(Rx2.expand(body => { // recurse the api until no more cursors
      return body.response_metadata && 
        body.response_metadata.next_cursor ? 
        getChannel(body.response_metadata.next_cursor) : Rx.EMPTY
    }))
    .pipe(Rx2.pluck('channels'))
    .pipe(Rx2.mergeAll()) // flattens array
    .pipe(Rx2.filter(c => {
      console.log('finding', c.name === 'development')
      return c.name === 'development'
    }))
}
```

Comment: I didn't edit the answer to respond. I edited it because I work with him and, while he solved it, he didn't answer the solution to the fullest clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this is the functionality you are looking for https://codepen.io/jeremytru91/pen/wOQxbZ?editors=1111

```
const {
  of,
  EMPTY
} = rxjs;

const {
  filter,
  tap,
  expand,
  take,
  pluck,
  concatAll,
  flatMap,
  first
} = rxjs.operators;

function* apiResponses() {
  yield of({channels: [{id: 123, name: 'test'}, {id:4, name: 'hello'}], cursor: 1});
  yield of({channels:[{id: 3, name: 'react'}, {id: 5, name: 'devcap'}], cursor:3});
  yield of({channels:[{id: 1, name: 'world'}, {id: 2, name: 'knows'}], cursor: 2});
  yield of({channels:[{id: 4, name: 'react'}, {id: 6, name: 'devcap'}], cursor:4});
}

let gen = apiResponses();

function getChannel() {
  return gen.next().value // simulate api call
    .pipe(
      expand(body => {
        return body.cursor ? gen.next().value : EMPTY
      }),
      pluck('channels'),
      flatMap(channels => {
        const filtered = channels.filter(channel => channel.name === 'devcap')
        if(filtered.length) {
          return filtered;
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    first()
    );
}


getChannel().subscribe(data => {
  console.log('DATA!! ', data)
  }, e => {
  console.log('ERROR', e)
  throw e
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The `find` callback should return a boolean, not an Observable. E.g.

```js
find(c => c.name === 'development')
```

**UPDATE**

Heres a modified example of yours. I've removed generators as they are more complicated then our case needs.

```js
const { of, EMPTY, throwError } = rxjs;
const { filter, tap, expand, pluck, mergeAll } = rxjs.operators;

const DATA = 
  [ {channels: [{id: 123, name: 'test'}, {id:4, name: 'hello'}], cursor: 1}
  , {channels:[{id: 1, name: 'world'}, {id: 2, name: 'knows'}], cursor: 2}
  , {channels:[{id: 3, name: 'react'}, {id: 5, name: 'devcap'}], cursor: false}
  ];

function getChannel(){
  return getBlock()
    .pipe(
        expand(x => x.cursor ? getBlock(x.cursor) : EMPTY),
        pluck('channels'),
        mergeAll(),
        filter(c => c.name === 'devcap')
    )
}

getChannel().subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error
});


function getBlock(index = 0) {
  if (index >= DATA.length){
    throwError('Out of bounds');
  }

  return of(DATA[index]);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Your solution didn't work due to recursion being done through solely `getChannel()`. When you do the `expand` -- you run another cycle through `getChannel()`. Meaning that you run `pluck-mergeAll-filter` chain twice on each recursively fetched value! Plucking and flattering it twice gives you `undefined` -- therefore the error.

In your playground -- try separating out this code

```js
let getValue = ()=>{
    const next = gen.next();
    if (!next || !next.value) { return EMPTY; }
    return next.value;
}
```

and use it in the expand, like this:

```js
let getChannel = () => {
   return getValue()
      .pipe(
        expand(body => {
          return body.cursor ? getValue() : EMPTY
        }),
        pluck('channels'),
        mergeAll(),
        filter(c => c.name === 'devcap'),
      )
}
```

Comment: I've changed to a boolean and also changed `find` to `filter`. I am getting error: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: @courtyen , its hard to say, though seems like this error comes from `expand()`. When you're done with recursion -- try returning [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/EMPTY) instead of `undefined`

Comment: I updated per your comment with a ternary inside my `expand`. I am unfortunately still receiving the same error as above.

Comment: From the logs I am seeing that error get emitted before I hit my last cursor.

Comment: @courtyen, again, its hard to trace the error visually, so its little that I could help with. Place a console.log as first line of your `getChannel` fn and a `tap` as first operator you pipe after `getData`. Also, you might drop the latest three `pipes` -- just for debugging purpose.

Comment: @courtyen, if you could provide a playground example -- we could be of better help.

Comment: Thanks Kos for your help with this. Give me some time and I will provide a playground.

Comment: Kos, here is a playground: https://codepen.io/courtneynguyen/full/ZPmrLj

Comment: @courtyen, I've updated my answer with a modified example of yours. Still trying to understand why the example with generators fails. Generators have always been a tough nut for me.